# Как решать git-конфликты при rebase, merge?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

Как решать конфликты, которые возникают при `rebase`, `merge`? Какие для этого есть инструменты и техники?

Comment: а на каком этапе Вы остановились? как выйти с этого редактора который бибикает и портит текст? или " у меня тут слияние 8 веток"?

Comment: здравый смысл и текстовый редактор. других инструментов, вроде, нет.

Comment: Пользуюсь Inteliju Idea очень класно помогает визуально решать конфликты

Comment: У каждого редактора есть плагин, который позволяет визуализировать конфликт и позволяет например выбрать тот или иной вариант в один клик. Но без здравого смысла - никак, согласна с aleksandr barakin